# How do i link third party libraries in a makefile on ubuntu (g++)

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, g++

I am trying to link the cpptest library for unittesting to my project and have no idea how to link third party libraries in my Makefile. Coud you give me a sample code or a good tutorial? i haven't found any good ones